# Android Hybrid Mobile App CORS Issues. No Internet Connection

Tags: android, cors, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing and testing a hybrid app which runs perfectly on IOS 8-11 and as a Chrome Web App and as a Mac and Windows desktop app under NWJS.

This app has also run perfectly on Android up to 5.0 Lollipop. However on later versions on Android (6.0 Marshmallow and 7.0 Nougat and 8.0 Oreo) the app works sucessfully on some devices but cannot access the internet on others.

The specific issue is that where the app does not work properly, it is that the CORS preflight checks fail with the following error message "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Now I repeat, the app works perfectly on some installations of Android, including up to 7.0 Nougat, but fails on many other Android devices running 6.0,7.0 or 8.0. I had no issues at all up to Android 5.0

Could this be that some makers of Android devices are using different browsers for implementing their web views? Or is there some setting I need to add to my app manifest?

I am tearing my hair out, all help very gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by setting

setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs
and setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs  both to true

However this was a change moving from Android 3 to 4 so why on earth I tripped up on it upgrading from 5 to 6 is beyond my understanding.